# How to manage UITextField move up when the keyboard is present - in case of multiple textFields are present?

Tags: ios, swift

This is my view controller.

[image]

I am trying to move the textFields up while the keyboard is covering textFields of the bottom of the screen. Here is the code I've done :

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        txtFName.delegate = self
        txtLName.delegate = self
        txtCompany.delegate = self
        txtStreet1.delegate = self
        txtStreet2.delegate = self
        txtTown.delegate = self
        txtPin.delegate = self
        txtPhone.delegate = self
        txtEmail.delegate = self
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(self.keyBoardWillChange(notification:)),
            name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(self.keyBoardWillChange(notification:)),
            name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(self.keyBoardWillChange(notification:)),
            name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("Return Tapped")
        txtFName.resignFirstResponder()
        txtLName.resignFirstResponder()
        txtCompany.resignFirstResponder()
        txtStreet1.resignFirstResponder()
        txtStreet2.resignFirstResponder()
        txtTown.resignFirstResponder()
        txtPin.resignFirstResponder()
        txtPhone.resignFirstResponder()
        txtEmail.resignFirstResponder()
        view.frame.origin.y = 0
        return true
    }
    
    @objc func keyBoardWillChange(notification: Notification) {
        print("Keyboard will show: \(notification.name.rawValue)")
        view.frame.origin.y = -250
    }
```

Now while I am tapping on any of the textFields, the whole view is moving up. "txtFName", "txtLName".. these textFields are not being visible.

I want to move up the view only when I would tap on "txtPin", "txtPhone", "txtEmail". Rest textfields would remain in the default position even when the keyboard appears.

what the required changes are?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a UITextField move up when the keyboard is present - on starting to edit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-can-i-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-the-keyboard-is-present-on-starting)

Comment: No. But it's been solved in some other way. Thanks.

Comment: if the question is solved, you should either close the question or add an answer so that future readers may use the same solution as you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can use your `isFirstResponder` property on your text field. When true, it means that this is the text field you wish to focus on and move upwards when it starts being edited.

```
@objc private func keyBoardWillChange(notification: Notification) {
    let possibleTextFields: [UITextField] = [txtLName, txtCompany, txtStreet1, txtStreet2, txtTown, txtPin, txtPhone, txtEmail]
    let focusedTextField: UITextField? = possibleTextFields.first { $0.isFirstResponder }
    ...
}
```

Now that you have that you would still need to calculate the offset that is needed to move your view

**Getting the frame of keyboard:**

```
guard let info = notification.userInfo else { return }
guard let value: NSValue = info[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }
let newFrame = value.cgRectValue
```

**Computing the difference**

There are tools to check frames which allow you to convert frames to different coordinate systems (views)

```
private func getVerticalDifference(keyboardFrame: CGRect, viewToFocus: UIView, panel: UIView) -> CGFloat {
    let keyboardInPanel = panel.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)
    let viewInPanel = panel.convert(viewToFocus.bounds, from: viewToFocus)
    
    return viewInPanel.maxY - keyboardInPanel.minY
}
```

I suggest you use the view of your view controller for your `panel` parameter it should be something that is not being changed (Which is not the case in your current code. Avoid changing frame of the view of your view controller).

**Applying the difference:**

To apply the difference I suggest that you use constraints. Put all your text fields on a single "panel" view. This view may best also put into a scroll view so user may scroll through it on smaller devices. Now panel (or scroll view) can have a low priority (500 for instance) bottom constraint to view controller. Then another high priority bottom constraint set to `greaterThan` meaning that bottom will be fixed to "greater than X" where X can be setup later.

Now you can drag an outlet to your code from this `greaterThan` constraint. And then all you need to do is

```
bottomConstraintOutlet.constant = max(0.0, getVerticalDifference(...))
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But it's been solved in some other way.